# Como obtener los datos de un marcador desde firebase en Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion en android con java, huawei maps y firebase pero tengo un problema que no puedo resolver hace días es que al apretar el marcador del mapa y mostrar los datos en los TextView solo me muestra el ultimo registro de mi base de datos y no de el marcador el cual seleccione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las imágenes de código no son aceptables, te recomiendo que leas [ask] para evitar que tu pregunta acabe cerrada. Y viendo que eres miembro desde hace 3 años, eso ya deberías de saberlo!

Comment: @Benito-B Hola primero trate de copiar el codigo pero no me dejaba publicar la pregunta porque era demasiado largo por lo que opte en subirla imagen del codigo